# Google Earth KML clampToGround allows subterranean lines

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am creating a Google Earth KML, and having trouble. My `LineString` won't stay above ground. I'm using `clampToGround` as [instructed](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#syntax_86) in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148078?hl=en), I think.

Why doesn't `clampToGround` keep the `LineString` above the ground here? If I'm reading the documentation right, it really should stay above the ground. I tried to work around it by going `relativeToGround` and giving it a little altitude, but that didn't work either. I just want to make sure the line is visible above ground for its whole length.

Salient portions of the KML:

```
<Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Path</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                86.66797376467392,48.79933074280933,100 87.52400441880934,49.14303840409646,100 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Path2</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                86.66797376467392,48.81933074280933,10 87.52400441880934,49.15303840409646,10 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Path3</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                86.66797376467392,48.91933074280933,10 87.52400441880934,49.25303840409646,10 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```

The more I zoom in, the more gets occluded but the ground. How do I stop this?
[image: Screenshot. Camera is at 11000+ ft]

I can still cause this to happen, even if drawing when very zoomed in:
[image]

Here's the KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>aaaa.kml</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Path</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                -110.8533929259622,43.78725268338503,0 -110.8487894073726,43.78768726798314,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Have you tried it w/o `altitudeMode`?

Comment: @rheitzman Yes. The same issue occurs without the `altitudeMode` tag. What's interesting is if I draw with the UI tools, it doesn't seem to do this. Then, after I export to KML and reopen it, this happens.

Comment: Before you export copy the layer to the clipboard to capture the current KML. Then compare the clipboard KML to the exported KML. Maybe you'll see the difference that is causing the problem.

Comment: I think this may be related to the resolution of the line. If you zoom in on an area and draw the line when you zoom out the line is OK. If at the zoom out altitude you draw a similar line it may exhibit the problems when you are zoomed in.

Comment: @rheitzman The clipboard and export versions are the same. I've updated the question with a picture where I can still get it to happen even if I drew it when I was zoomed in. I'm a little surprised there's not more out there about this. Perhaps my search queries are not good enough to find the right answer.

Comment: See resolution comment above - if you zoom in to draw the line it will work OK. Try a zoom in to a line, draw another at the altitude, and check the KML of the two lines. My guess is you will see many more points on the low altitude version.

Comment: @rheitzman Ah. So the difference here is I'm using a LineString with exactly two points. I only know the start and end point.

Comment: Google Earth does an adequate job IMO, but it isn't a GIS program so my expectations are not that high. For my purposes I flatten (0.01 exaggeration)  the terrain so all our lines appear just fine. FYI there is a terrain profile view if you are interested in elevation change along a line - right click a line and pick Show Elevation Profile.

Comment: @rheitzman Nice! I didn't know about that. You're right. It's not a GIS program, and it does okay. :-)